# c# - Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've been trying to get this to work, but no luck.

I have middleware class where used to verify uploaded files.

After middleware debug goes to the Controller class, but not to the action. Context Request ending after controller's constructor.

Middleware class:

```
 public class UploadMiddleware
{

    public UploadMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

        [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var authToken = context.Request.Headers["id"].ToString();
        var path = context.Request.Path.ToString();
        var streamBody = context.Request.Body;

            if (authToken != String.Empty)
            {
                if (!IsMultipartContentType(context.Request.ContentType))
                {
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unexpected error.");  
                    await _next(context);              
                    return;
                }

                var boundary = GetBoundary(context.Request.ContentType); 
                var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, context.Request.Body);
                // reader.HeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
                // reader.BodyLengthLimit = long.MaxValue;

                var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
                var buffer = new byte[256];
                while (section != null)
                {
                    var fileName = GetFileName(section.ContentDisposition);
                    var bytesRead = 0;

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName,FileMode.Append))
                    {                                         
                        do{

                            bytesRead = await section.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);       
                             buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
                       } while (bytesRead < 0);                   
                    }


                    if (!verifyUpcomingFiles(buffer))
                    {
                        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Undefined file type detected.");
                        return;
                    }
                     else
                     {
                      context.Request.Headers.Add("isVerified","verified");                                                    
                    }


                     section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();      
                }


            }
            else
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("You are not allowed to complete this process.");
                return;

            }
            await _next(context);


    }
```

I am stuck in this problem. I really need someone point me in a direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just noticed after a quick scan, should the "while (bytesRead < 0);" actually be "while (bytesRead > 0);"? Not sure if that's your issue but it looks wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear, as well as the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x#creating-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder) are and warns you about it in **big red box**:

> ### Warning
>
> Do not call `next.Invoke` after the response has been sent to the client. Changes to `HttpResponse` after the response has started will throw an exception. For example, changes such as setting headers, status code, etc, will throw an exception. Writing to the response body after calling `next`:
>
> - May cause a protocol violation. For example, writing more than the stated content-length.
> - May corrupt the body format. For example, writing an HTML footer to a CSS file.
>
> `HttpResponse.HasStarted` is a useful hint to indicate if headers have been sent and/or the body has been written to.

```
if (!IsMultipartContentType(context.Request.ContentType))
{
    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Unexpected error.");  
    // Here you're calling the next middleware after writing to the response stream!
    await _next(context);              
    return;
}
```